# Writing a text based game, I'm confused as to how to check input on button press and then update

Tags: java, applet

So far I have a main class, messages class and an answers class. The messages and answers are stored in separate arrays so I can pull them out when needed. However, I am unsure as to how to proceed. I need to check what the user has entered when they hit the proceed button with the corresponding array of answers for that message. (One message will have it's own array of answers to check). If there is a better way of doing this i.e with a case statement for each message please let me know. Here's the code:

Main:

```
package com.game.main;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends Applet {

private TextField commandInput;
private TextArea messageDisplay;
private Button button;
public Message messages;
private String currentLevel;

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;
private ActionListener action;

public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread();
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Initialisation method
public void init() {
    super.init();

    messages = new Message();
    // Define colours
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setForeground(Color.black);

    Panel appletPanel = new Panel();

    // Use a border layout
    BorderLayout b = new BorderLayout();
    appletPanel.setLayout(b);
    add(appletPanel);

    this.setSize(800, 400);

    // Define UI items
    commandInput = new TextField(20);
    messageDisplay = new TextArea(null, 20, 60, TextArea.SCROLLBARS_NONE); // 20 rows x 60 chars
    button = new Button("Proceed");
    Panel inputPanel = new Panel();

    // Add components to our layout / panels
    inputPanel.add(commandInput);
    inputPanel.add(button);
    appletPanel.add(messageDisplay, "North");
    appletPanel.add(inputPanel, "South");

    currentLevel = messages.messageArray[0];
    messageDisplay.append(messages.messageArray[0]);

    run();
}

// game loop
public void run() {
    requestFocus();
    // read as while "running == true"
    while (running) {

    }
}
```

}

Messages:

```
package com.game.main;

public class Message {

public String[] messageArray;

public Message() {
    messageArray = new String[50];
    messageArray[0] = "Welcome.";
}
}
```

Answers:

```
package com.game.main;

public class Answers {

public String[] introAnswers;

public Answers() {
    introAnswers = new String[2];
    introAnswers[0] = "Go";
    introAnswers[1] = "go";
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an [`EventListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html) so your program can detect when the button has been pressed and check for the text in the textArea. Check out this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/).

Here is a simple generic example:

```
button.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        message = textArea.getText();
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```